# Tips for optimizing parallelism with lidR custom metric to be deployed on HPC

Tags: lidr

I've read the documentation on parallel computation in lidR in the lidR [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/lidR.pdf) (page 73) and am a bit lost about how to optimize or effectively implement parallelism on a high-performance computer cluster (with many computers; >300 cores available and ~1800GB of RAM).
I need to:

1. Normalize my point cloud
2. Run a custom grid metric
3. Write the script so that it will run the task in parallel on many cores as is reasonable on an HPC

My questions are:

1. Can I normalize the point cloud and calculate my custom grid metric in one step (i.e., is this script written optimally)?
2. Does it make sense to chunk a las catalog, given I will have many cores to work with? Does this speed things up?
3. I understand that the `normalize_height()` function is semi-parallelized. If this function is nested within a chunked catalog, is this optimal? There are cautionary notes against nested parallelism in the documentation.
4. Would there be any benefit to using `catalog_retile()`?

I tested my code with chunking and without chunking on my personal computer with 4 cores and only noticed a slight improvement across 4 tiles (1kmx1km) (~14mins vs. ~15.5mins).

I will be scaling this up to 23,581 tiles (10 TB data) so any optimization will save major $$ in compute time.

Here is my script:

```
require(lidR)
library(raster)
library(future)

start_time <- Sys.time()

shrub_cover_calc = function(Z) {
  n_shrub = sum(Z >= 0.3 & Z <= 2.5)
  n_veg = sum(Z <= 2.5)
  return(list(ratio = n_shrub/n_veg))
}

shrub_cover_metric = function(las) {
  nlas <- normalize_height(las, tin())
  shrub_cover_raster <- grid_metrics(nlas, ~shrub_cover_calc(Z), res = 10)
  return(shrub_cover_raster)
}

shrub_cover_chunk = function(chunk)
{
  las <- readLAS(chunk)                          
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)         # check if it actually contain points
  shrub_cover_raster <- shrub_cover_metric(las)
  return(shrub_cover_raster)
}

ctg <- readLAScatalog("data/raw/nb/manual")

plan(multisession, workers = 4L) # 4 cores, scale up once on HPC
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 300
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 40
options <- list(automerge = TRUE) # merge all the outputs

shrub_cover_ctg <- catalog_apply(ctg, shrub_cover_chunk, .options = options)
plot(shrub_cover_ctg)

end_time <- Sys.time()

print(paste0("The script took ", end_time - start_time, " mins"))
```

Comment: HPC may have various meaning. What do you mean? Are you using many computers with many cores? One computer with many cores?  Are the different workers able to read on the same disk? Are you limited by the RAM? You must define clearly what is a HPC in your context.

Comment: You may want to read https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/wiki/Make-cheap-High-Performance-Computing-to-process-large-datasets

Comment: I am using a high-performance computer cluster with many computers. There are >300 cores available and ~1800GB of RAM. I'm not sure if the workers are able to read on the same disk..

Comment: I added `shrub_cover_raster <- raster::crop(shrub_cover_raster, raster::extent(las)) # remove buffer` to my script based on JRR's feedback.

Comment: You must know the architecture of your HPC to know what strategy to use for parallelization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Can I normalize the point cloud and calculate my custom grid metric in one step (i.e., is this script written optimally)?

Your script looks good but you missed to remove the buffer (see [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-catalog-apply-examples.html)). It is optimal? It depends. If you perform several processing you will need to normalize several times your point cloud. This is sub-optimal.If you want to do it once and do not want to save the normalized point cloud it will do the job.

> 2. Does it make sense to chunk a las catalog, given I will have many cores to work with? Does this speed things up?

There are always chunks. I guess you mean *chunks smaller than the tiles*. Hard to say. Parallelism is complex. It depends on your RAM. If you do not have enough RAM to load and process 4 tiles at the same time you are maybe better to load 4 quarters of a tiles. Maybe not, it depends on the complexity of the task, on the time required to read the files. You must test and try. I'm usually not using more than half of the available worker.

> 3. I understand that the normalize_height() function is semi-parallelized. If this function is nested within a chunked catalog, is this optimal? There are cautionary notes against nested parallelism in the documentation.

lidR handles this case internally. Internal parallelization of `tin()` will be disabled.

> 4. Would there be any benefit to using catalog_retile()?

Never. `catalog_retile()` is a *convenient* function that may be useful to process data in another software or to retile in a specific way but you never need to retile to work with lidR. This is written in the doc of the function

> Note that this function is not actually very useful because lidR manages everything (clipping, processing, buffering, ...) internally using the proper options. Thus, retiling may be useful for working in other software, for example, but not in lidR

What you do need however is to spatially index your point cloud with lax files (see [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-computation-speed-LAScatalog.html)). Also if your catalog is large you also need to use `opt_output_files()` do to not have the entire raster in R memory.

---

```r
library(lidR)
library(raster)
library(future)

start_time <- Sys.time()

shrub_cover_calc = function(Z) {
  n_shrub = sum(Z >= 0.3 & Z <= 2.5)
  n_veg = sum(Z <= 2.5)
  return(list(ratio = n_shrub/n_veg))
}

shrub_cover_metric = function(las) {
  nlas <- normalize_height(las, tin())
  shrub_cover_raster <- grid_metrics(nlas, ~shrub_cover_calc(Z), res = 10)
  return(shrub_cover_raster)
}

ctg <- readLAScatalog("data/raw/nb/manual")

plan(multisession, workers = 4L)
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 300
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 40

shrub_cover_ctg <- catalog_map(ctg, shrub_cover_metric)
```